# SQL inputting missing IDs from one table onto another

Tags: sql

So I'm attempting to take some values from one table (tblIDs) and input into another table (tbldailylog) and fill in some default values on each day when those IDs are not already logged into the system through other means.

Each day some IDs that are on tblIDs get logged into tbldailylog, but some are left off.  The query would ideally compare the IDs from the two tables on the given date, and add those that are not on tbldailylog but are on tblIDs to tbldailylog (and then potentially set some default options for if they were autologged).

```
INSERT INTO `tbldailylog` (`logID`,`LogDate`,`Issue`,`Notes`) 
SELECT `ID`,`LogDate`,'0','AUTO-LOGGED' 
FROM `tblIDs`,`tbldailylog` 
WHERE DATE(`Date`) = CURDATE() 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT `logID`,`ID` FROM `tbldailylog`,`tblIDs` 
WHERE `logID` = `ID`)
```

This query just isn't doing anything (no error message) and most things that I have tried have gotten nowhere.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your code uses non-standard SQL). Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Unrelated, but: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251

Answer (score 0):

You need *table* alise :

```
INSERT INTO tbldailylog (`logID`,`LogDate`,`Issue`,`Notes`) 
SELECT `ID`,`LogDate`,'0','AUTO-LOGGED' 
FROM tblIDs i
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM tbldailylog l 
                  WHERE i.id = l.logID AND 
                        DATE(l.Date) = CURDATE()
                  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . .  I'm thinking `NOT EXISTS` and no joins:

```
INSERT INTO tbldailylog (logID, LogDate, Issue, Notes) 
    SELECT i.ID, i.LogDate, '0', 'AUTO-LOGGED' 
    FROM tblIDs i
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM tbldailylog dl
                      WHERE DATE(dl.Date) = CURDATE() AND dl.logID = i.id
                     );
```